# R random forest cross validation using the caret train function doesn't produce the same accuracy as when done by hand

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm building a random forest on some data from work (this means I can't share that data, there are 15k observations), using the caret train function for cross validation, the accuracy of the model is very low: 0.9%.

here's the code I used:

```
set.seed(512)
n <- nrow(my_data)

train_indices <- sample(1:n)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_indices, k=5)

model <- train(ICNumber ~ ., tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32), min.node.size = 1, splitrule = "gini"),
                 data = my_data, method = "ranger",
                 trControl = trainControl(verboseIter = TRUE, savePredictions = T, index=my_folds))

print(model$resample)
```

--Edit
As Gilles noticed, the folds indices are wrongly constructed and training is done on 20% of the observations, but even if I fix this by adding `returnTrain = T`  , I'm still getting near zero accuracy
--Edit

model$resample produces this:

```
Accuracy ___ Kappa_____ Resample  
0.026823683_ 0.0260175246_ Fold1  
0.002615234_ 0.0019433907_ Fold2  
0.002301118_ 0.0017644472_ Fold3  
0.001637733_ 0.0007026352_ Fold4  
0.010187315_ 0.0094986595_ Fold5
```

Now if I do the cross validation by hand like this:

```
set.seed(512)
n <- nrow(my_data)

train_indices <- sample(1:n)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_indices, k=5)

for (fold in my_folds) {
  train_data <- my_data[-fold,]
  test_data <- my_data[fold,]

  model <- train(ICNumber ~ ., tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32), min.node.size = 1, splitrule = "gini"),
                 data = train_data, method = "ranger",
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "none"))

  p <- predict(model, test_data)
  e <- ifelse(p == test_data$ICNumber, T, F)
  print(sum(e) / nrow(test_data))
}
```

I get the following accuracy:

```
[1] 0.743871  
[1] 0.7566957  
[1] 0.7380645  
[1] 0.7390181  
[1] 0.7311168
```

I was expecting to get about the same accuracy values, what am I doing wrong in train? Or is the manual prediction code wrong?

--Edit
Furthermore, this code works well on the Soybean data and I can reproduce the results from Gilles below
--Edit

--Edit2
Here are some details about my data:
15493 obs. of  17 variables:
ICNUmber is a string with 1531 different values, these are the classes
the other 16 variables are factors with 33 levels
--Edit2

--Edit3
My last experiment was to drop the observations for all the classes occurring less than 10 times, 12k observations of 396 classes remained. For this dataset, the manual and automatic cross validations accuracy match...
--Edit3

Comment: When running the automatic cross validation, there's a warning "Dropped unused factor level(s) in dependent variable:..." for each fold, this does not happen during the manual cross validation.

Comment: And if I drop classes that have less than 4 observations, then the warnings go away and the accuracy is the same for manual or automatic cross validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the train function transforms the class column into a factor, in my dataset there are a lot (about 20%) of classes that have less than 4 observations. When splitting the set by hand, the factor is constructed after the split and for each of the factor value there's at least one observation.
But during the automatic cross validation, the factor is constructed on the full dataset and when the splits are done some values of the factor don't have any observation. This seems to somehow mess up the accuracy. This probably calls for a new different question, thanks to Gilles and missuse for their help.

Answer (score 4):

It was a tricky one ! ;-)
The error comes from a misuse of the `index` option in `trainControl`.

According tho the help page, `index` should be :

> a list with elements for each resampling iteration. Each list element is a vector of integers corresponding to the rows used for training at that iteration.

In your code you provided the integers coresponding to the rows that should be removed
from the training dataset instead of providing the integers corresponding to the
rows that should be used...

You can cange that by using `createFolds(train_indices, k=5, returnTrain = T)` instead
of `createFolds(train_indices, k=5)`.
Note also that internaly, afaik, `caret` is creating folds that are balanced relative
to the classes that you want to predict. So the code should ideally be more like :
`createFolds(my_data[train_indices, "Class"], k=5, returnTrain = T)`, particularly
if the classes are not balanced...

Here is a reproducible example with the Soybean dataset

```r
library(caret)
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : lattice
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : ggplot2
data(Soybean, package = "mlbench")
my_data <- droplevels(na.omit(Soybean))
```

Your code (the training data is here much smaller than expected, you use only 20% of the data, hence the lower accuracy).
You also get some warnings due to the absense of some classes in the training datasets (because of the class imbalance and reduced training set).

```r
set.seed(512)
n <- nrow(my_data)

train_indices <- sample(1:n)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_indices, k=5)

model <- train(Class ~ ., tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32), min.node.size = 1, splitrule = "gini"),
               data = my_data, method = "ranger",
               trControl = trainControl(verboseIter = F, savePredictions = T, 
                                        index=my_folds))
#> Warning: Dropped unused factor level(s) in dependent variable: rhizoctonia-
#> root-rot.
#> Warning: Dropped unused factor level(s) in dependent variable: downy-
#> mildew.

print(model$resample)
#>    Accuracy     Kappa Resample
#> 1 0.7951002 0.7700909    Fold1
#> 2 0.5846868 0.5400131    Fold2
#> 3 0.8440980 0.8251373    Fold3
#> 4 0.8822222 0.8679453    Fold4
#> 5 0.8444444 0.8263563    Fold5
```

Corrected code, just with `returnTrain = T` (here you really use 80% of the data for training...)

```r
set.seed(512)
n <- nrow(my_data)

train_indices <- sample(1:n)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_indices, k=5, returnTrain = T)

model <- train(Class ~ ., tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32), min.node.size = 1, splitrule = "gini"),
               data = my_data, method = "ranger",
               trControl = trainControl(verboseIter = F, savePredictions = T, 
                                        index=my_folds))

print(model$resample)
#>    Accuracy     Kappa Resample
#> 1 0.9380531 0.9293371    Fold1
#> 2 0.8750000 0.8583687    Fold2
#> 3 0.9115044 0.9009814    Fold3
#> 4 0.8660714 0.8505205    Fold4
#> 5 0.9107143 0.9003825    Fold5
```

To be compared to your loop. There are still some small differences so maybe there is still something that I don't understand.

```r
set.seed(512)
n <- nrow(my_data)

train_indices <- sample(1:n)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_indices, k=5)

for (fold in my_folds) {
    train_data <- my_data[-fold,]
    test_data <- my_data[fold,]

    model <- train(Class ~ ., tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32), min.node.size = 1, splitrule = "gini"),
                   data = train_data, method = "ranger",
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "none"))

    p <- predict(model, test_data)
    e <- ifelse(p == test_data$Class, T, F)
    print(sum(e) / nrow(test_data))
}
#> [1] 0.9380531
#> [1] 0.875
#> [1] 0.9115044
#> [1] 0.875
#> [1] 0.9196429
```

Created on 2018-03-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for having a look,  at first is was using "trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, verboseIter = TRUE))". My understanding is this should make 5 folds and keep each in turn for testing, I was also getting very low accuracy and then I added the index parameter in an attempt to do a fair comparison with the "by hand" method, it seems I messed up its value. I'll give it a shot anyway tomorrow.

Comment: I just tested this and I'm still getting near zero accuracy, training on 20% will for sure decrease the model accuracy as shown by your example but I'm hitting something else here.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the excellent answer by Gilles. Apart the mistake in specifying the indexes used for testing and training, to get a fully reproducible model for algorithms that involve some stochastic process like random forrest you should specify the `seeds` argument in `trainControl`. The length of this argument should equal the number of re-samples + 1 (for the final model):

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

data(Sonar)

set.seed(512)
n <- nrow(Sonar)
train_indices <- sample(1:n)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_indices, k = 5, returnTrain = T)

model <- train(Class ~ .,
               tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32),
                                     min.node.size = 1,
                                     splitrule = "gini"),
               data = Sonar,
               method = "ranger",
               trControl = trainControl(verboseIter = F,
                                        savePredictions = T, 
                                        index = my_folds,
                                        seeds = rep(512, 6))) #this is the important part

 model$resample
#output
   Accuracy     Kappa Resample
1 0.8536585 0.6955446    Fold1
2 0.8095238 0.6190476    Fold2
3 0.8536585 0.6992665    Fold3
4 0.7317073 0.4786127    Fold4
5 0.8372093 0.6681367    Fold5
```

now lets do the resample manually:

```
for (fold in my_folds) {
  train_data <- Sonar[fold,]
  test_data <- Sonar[-fold,]
  model <- train(Class ~ .,
                 tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = c(32),
                                       min.node.size = 1,
                                       splitrule = "gini"),
                 data = train_data,
                 method = "ranger",
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "none",
                                          seeds = 512)) #use the same seeds as above

  p <- predict(model, test_data)
  e <- ifelse(p == test_data$Class, T, F)
  print(sum(e) / nrow(test_data))
}
#output
[1] 0.8536585
[1] 0.8095238
[1] 0.8536585
[1] 0.7317073
[1] 0.8372093
```

@semicolo if you can reproduce this example on the Sonar data set, but not with your own data, then the problem is in the data set and any further insights will need to investigate the data in question.

Comment: Thanks! This was the missing part that explains the small differences between the manual method and the automatic one. I am indeed able to reproduce this on the Sonar data, (by the way the for { return} syntax doesn't seem to work very well, accuracy is NULL, but since model is overwritten in the loop, model$resample is also NULL and equals accuracy, but I see your point).   Alas it doesn't work on my data, it's either 74% for the manual method and 1% else, I'll add some details about the data at the end of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will edit the answer when I get to a PC. I do not understand how you expect to predict a string with so many levels. That is less than 10 obs per target class assuming balanced data.

Comment: No the data is not well balanced, in fact I have several data sets, this is the smallest one. I wasn't really expecting it to work, I'm just confused by the difference in accuracy between the automatic an manual cross validation methods.

Comment: @missuse : thanks a lot for the additional explanation. Very useful !